# Strange behavior of b:dataTable

Tags: bootsfaces

I use the component b: dataTable with responsive = "true", when I change the size of the browser on the PC and reduce the window width, it works perfectly, BUT, when I test the same page on a real 5" phone, the data table loses all its characteristics (It does not hide the values in the first cell The icon of sorting in the column headings, footer, pager, column visibility buttons, Copy and CSV, all disappear).
All the others responsives components works fine.

My b:dataTable code:

```
<b:row id="idFilaDatosHistoricos">
    <b:dataTable id="idReport" var="rep" style="width:100%"
        value="#{operationReportBean.report}"
        rendered="#{not empty operationReportBean.report}"
        searching="false" lang="es" copy="true" csv="true" excel="true"
        columnVisibility="true" scroll-horizontally="true" col-xs="12"
        responsive="true">

        <b:dataTableColumn value="#{rep.service.contractNumber}"
            label="#{msg['servicio']}"></b:dataTableColumn>
        <b:dataTableColumn value="#{rep.service.phoneNumber}"
            label="#{msg['telefono']}"></b:dataTableColumn>
        <b:dataTableColumn value="#{rep.service.referenceNumber}"
            label="#{msg['telRefShort']}"></b:dataTableColumn>
        <b:dataTableColumn label="#{msg['date']}">
            <h:outputText value="#{rep.date}" style="font-size: 10px;">
                <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                    timeZone="America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires" />
            </h:outputText>
        </b:dataTableColumn>
        <b:dataTableColumn value="#{rep.technician}"
            label="#{msg['tecnichian']}"></b:dataTableColumn>
        <b:dataTableColumn label="#{msg['tipoOperacion']}">
            <ui:param name="idTypeOperation" value="#{rep.type}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{msg[idTypeOperation]}" />
        </b:dataTableColumn>
        <b:dataTableColumn label="#{msg['stateOperation']}">
            <ui:param name="idStateOperation" value="#{rep.state}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{msg[idStateOperation]}" />
        </b:dataTableColumn>
        <b:dataTableColumn value="#{rep.serialNumber}"
            label="#{msg['serialNumber']}"></b:dataTableColumn>
        <b:dataTableColumn value="#{rep.serialNumberOld}"
            label="#{msg['serialOld']}"></b:dataTableColumn>
        <b:dataTableColumn value="#{rep.comments}"
            label="#{msg['comentarios']}"></b:dataTableColumn>
    </b:dataTable>
</b:row>
```

Comment: Could you add some more details? It is not clear what programming environment this is.

Comment: I'm using Bootsfaces 1.2.0, Primefaces 6.1, com.sun.faces.jsf-api 2.2.4, com.sun.faces.jsf-impl 2.2.17
Eclipse Luna, JBoss AS 7.1

Comment: Sounds like a JavaScript error. For some reason, your phone fails to execute the JavaScript code of the BootsFaces table. Does the code with without setting the `responsive` flag? Which phone are you using?

Comment: Most likely, there's an error message on the JavaScript console. You can access by connecting the phone with your development PC by an USB cable and remote debugging. In the case of Google Chrome, here's how to do it: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ If you're using another browser, there should be a similar option to debug remotely.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the problem is with the server, not with the device. In localhost, the page works as described, on my pre-production server, the page and the component work fine. The only thing is that the text in the footer and the pager is shown in Spanish and the text in the buttons (visibility of the column, copy) is shown in English, but that is not a major problem.